# Suggested jekyll theme doesn't work on Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have push the new site to `username.github.io`, and changed `theme` to `jekyll-theme-minimal` as suggested [here](https://pages.github.com/themes/)

But I'm keep getting 'Page build failed' email from Github without any description to the cause, I'm really new to using `jekyll`, maybe I have missed something,
This is the link to the site, https://github.com/cooperkong/cooperkong.github.io
thanks!

Comment: What steps did you follow?

Comment: I juat changed theme value in _config.xml

Comment: Does it work without the theme chAnge?

Comment: Yes it works with default theme 'minima'

Comment: My best guess is that it is something with spaces and/or tabs in `_config.yml`, difficult to spot the error without more information.

Comment: Hi @marcanuy just updated link, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the minimalistic theme is really minimalistic ;)

It only has a default layout and no includes, as they were being called in the other post files. After removing references to them and updating the Gemfile it works: [https://github.com/cooperkong/cooperkong.github.io/pull/1](https://github.com/marcanuy/cooperkong.github.io/commit/02d129b96d04f02e633ee4eb36ee4fb9dd533f07)

Removing from front matter `layout:page` and `layout:post` so it uses the default layout. And removing include liquid tags from pages `{% include ... %}`

Comment: I removed `layout` from all of the pages and any remaining Liquid tags but all it does was ignore `_includes/`. I didn't, however, add `github-pages` to my Gemfile because I'm using GitLab Pages. Here's my Repo: https://gitlab.com/aumars/umarsaid.

Comment: @PradanaAumars please add a new question, instead of a comment, explaining your situation.